# windows 8 javascript app print fragment doesnt print picture from a <div>

Tags: javascript, printing, windows-store-apps

I have this problem: ( i will attach code below ) I have a split screen template windows 8 app. In the right side of the screen I have a recipe with a picture in the top part. and a description in lower part. Both these 2 parts are in the same block . The picture and the text are shown from an array in data.js file. For example the picture is shown from var background:"images\recipes\picture1.jpg" and the description from var description:"example text bla bla bla". I create a document fragment that i clone and send it to print. Everything prints right, except the PICTURE. I get an X icon instead of the picture. Now I will write all the code I use for this. I have no ideea what is wrong. Everything is right in an example I follow. There it works, mine not.

Ready function add-ons:

```
document.getElementById("Print").addEventListener("click", PrintButtonHandler, false);

            // Register for Print Contract
            registerForPrintContract();
```

All code regarding printing:

```
function registerForPrintContract() {
        var printManager = Windows.Graphics.Printing.PrintManager.getForCurrentView();
        printManager.onprinttaskrequested = onPrintTaskRequested;
        WinJS.log && WinJS.log("Print Contract registered. Use Print button to print.", "sample", "status");
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Print event handler for printing via the PrintManager API. The user has to manually invoke
    /// the print charm after this function is executed.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="printEvent" type="Windows.Graphics.Printing.PrintTaskRequest">
    /// The event containing the print task request object.
    /// </param>
    function onPrintTaskRequested(printEvent) {
        var printTask = printEvent.request.createPrintTask("Print part", function (args) {
            var frag = document.createDocumentFragment();
            frag.appendChild(document.getElementById("print").cloneNode(true));
            args.setSource(MSApp.getHtmlPrintDocumentSource(frag));


            // Register the handler for print task completion event
            printTask.oncompleted = onPrintTaskCompleted;
        });
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Print Task event handler is invoked when the print job is completed.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="printTaskCompletionEvent" type="Windows.Graphics.Printing.PrintTaskCompleted">
    /// The event containing the print task completion object.
    /// </param>
    function onPrintTaskCompleted(printTaskCompletionEvent) {
        // Notify the user about the failure
        if (printTaskCompletionEvent.completion === Windows.Graphics.Printing.PrintTaskCompletion.failed) {
            WinJS.log && WinJS.log("Failed to print.", "sample", "error");
        }
    }


    function PrintButtonHandler() {
        // Optionally, functions to be executed immediately before and after printing can be configured as following:
        window.document.body.onbeforeprint = beforePrint;
        window.document.body.onafterprint = afterPrint;

        // If the print contract is registered, the print experience is invoked.
        Windows.Graphics.Printing.PrintManager.showPrintUIAsync();
    }

    var page = WinJS.UI.Pages.define("/page/split.html", {
        ready: function (element, options) {
            var dataTransferManager = Windows.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer.DataTransferManager.getForCurrentView();
            dataTransferManager.addEventListener("datarequested", dataRequested);
            document.getElementById("share").addEventListener("click", showShareUI, false);
        },
        unload: function () {
            var dataTransferManager = Windows.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer.DataTransferManager.getForCurrentView();
            dataTransferManager.removeEventListener("datarequested", dataRequested);
        }
    });

    function dataRequested(e) {
        var request = e.request;

        // Title is required
        var dataPackageTitle = document.getElementById("titluReteta").value;
        if ((typeof dataPackageTitle === "string") && (dataPackageTitle !== "")) {
            var range = document.createRange();
            range.selectNode(document.getElementById("print"));
            request.data = MSApp.createDataPackage(range);
            request.data.properties.title = dataPackageTitle;



            // The HTML fragment we are using has an image tag that references a local file accessible only to this application.
            // To make sure that target application can render this image, we need to populate a resourceMap as part of the share operation data
            // We use the image's relative src property as the key to the resourceMap item we're adding
            var path = document.getElementById("print").getAttribute("src");
            var imageUri = new Windows.Foundation.Uri(path);
            var streamReference = Windows.Storage.Streams.RandomAccessStreamReference.createFromUri(imageUri);
            request.data.resourceMap[path] = streamReference;
        } else {
            request.failWithDisplayText(SdkSample.missingTitleError);
        }
    }

    function showShareUI() {
        Windows.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer.DataTransferManager.showShareUI();
    }

})();
```

This the code from the page:

```
        </header>
        <img class="article-image" src="#" data-win-bind="src: backgroundImage; alt: title" style="border: 10px double #73513B;"  />
        <div class="article-content" data-win-bind="innerHTML: content"> </div>
    </article>
</div>
```

And the `data-win-bind` is the picture that doesnt print.

I added this line   `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/print.css" media="print" />`  and print.css contains this:

```
#rootGrid
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
}

#inputLabel, #outputLabel, #input, #statusMessage
{
    display: none;
}

.article
{
    border:none;
}
```

I really need a fast answer if anyone can solve this. I need this project to be send until Friday. And I am clueless, after lots of example I tried to follow. Thank you very much to the guy that will save me!

LE: I tried also a classic   inside the description field. The picture appear in the app, but the same result for printing: a big X icon instead of picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved by printing entire document with reformating CSS code for showing just what I want to show. Now it captures all pictures with no problem. No answer got for the initial problem with capturing only the picture.